# C++ assert with time stamp

Tags: c++, assert

is that possible to log information when assert failed with time stamp

ex.

```
int a = 10

assert( a > 100 );
```

then it will be failed and output just like with the timestamp as well

```
2013-12-02 , 17:00:05 assert failed !! (a > 100) line : 22
```

Thank you

Comment: wrap your own ASSERT on top of assert and log time first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`assert` is a macro (it has to be one, to give `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` information).

You could define your own. I would name it something else like `tassert` for readability reasons, perhaps like (untested code)

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define tassert(Cond) do {if (0 && (Cond)) {}; } while(0)
#else
#define tassert_at(Cond,Fil,Lin) do { if ((Cond)) {  \
   time_t now##Lin = time(NULL);                     \
   char tbuf##Lin [64]; struct tm tm##Lin;           \
   localtime_r(&now##Lin, &tm##Lin);                 \
   strftime (tbuf##Lin, sizeof(tbuf##Lin),           \
             "%Y-%m-%d,%T", &tm##Lin);               \
   fprintf(stderr, "tassert %s failure: %s %s:%d\n", \
           #Cond, tbuf##Lin, Fil, Lin);              \
   abort();   }} while(0)
#define tassert(Cond) tassert_at(Cond,__FILE__,__LINE__) 
#endif /*NDEBUG*/
```

I am using [cpp concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) `##` with `Lin` to lower probability of name collisions, and I am using [cpp stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) `#` to make a string out of `Cond` macro formal. The `Cond` is always expanded, to make sure the compiler catch syntactic errors in it even when disabling `tassert`  with `NDEBUG` as [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html) does.

One could put most of the code in the above macro in some function, e.g.

```
 void tassert_at_failure (const char* cond, const char* fil, int lin) {
   timer_t now = time(NULL);
   char tbuf[64]; struct tm tm;
   localtime_r (&now, &tm);
   strftime (tbuf, sizeof(tbuf), "%Y-%m-%d,%T", &tm);
   fprintf (stderr, "tassert %s failure: %s %s:%d\n",
            cond, tbuf, fil, lin);
   abort();
 }
```

and then just define (a bit like `<assert.h>` does...)

```
 #define tassert_at(Cond,Fil,Lin) do { if ((Cond)) {  \
    tassert_at_failure(#Cond, Fil, Lin); }} while(0)
```

but I don't like much that approach, because for debugging with `gdb` having  `abort()` being called in the macro is much easier (IMHO size of code for debugging executables does not matter at all; calling `abort` in a macro is much more convenient inside `gdb` - making shorter backtraces and avoiding one `down` command...). If you don't want `libc` portability and just use recent GNU `libc` you could simply redefine the Glibc specific `__assert_fail` function (see inside `<assert.h>` header file). YMMV.

BTW, in real C++ code I prefer to use `<<` for assertion-like debug outputs. This enables usage of my own `operator <<` outputting routines (if you give it as an additional macro argument) so I am thinking of (untested code!)

```
#define tassert_message_at(Cond,Out,Fil,Lin)         \
 do { if ((Cond)) {                                  \
   time_t now##Lin = time(NULL);                     \
   char tbuf##Lin [64]; struct tm tm##Lin;           \
   localtime_r(&now##Lin, &tm##Lin);                 \
   strftime (tbuf##Lin, sizeof(tbuf##Lin),           \
             "%Y-%m-%d,%T", &tm##Lin);               \
   std::clog << "assert " << #Cond << " failed "     \
             tbuf##Lin << " " << Fil << ":" << Lin   \
             << Out << std::endl;                    \
   abort (); } } while(0)
#define tassert_message(Cond,Out) \
    tassert_message_at(Cond,Out,__FILE__,__LINE__)
```

and then I would use `tassert_message(i>5,"i=" << i);`

BTW, you might want to use [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) instead of `fprintf` in your `tassert_at` macro.

Comment: Why so much code in the macro.  All the macro should do in case of failure is call an assertion_failed function, with the information that can't be immediately obtained inside the function.